# WPF Image with loading animation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make Image control in WPF to animate while loading source.

I have found a solution, bu prepared for Windows 8 Metro development and it contains `ImageOpened` event, which does not exist in normal WPF Image control.

Do you know any solution for making Image show loading animation while loading?

Maybe there are some libraries with that kind of Image Control?

Here's that ImageLoader control I have found for Win 8 dev:

```
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="imgDisplay" Source="{Binding ElementName=parent,Path=Source}"
           ImageFailed="OnImageFailed"
           ImageOpened="OnImageOpened" />
    <ContentControl
        Visibility="{Binding ElementName=parent,Path=IsLoading,Converter={StaticResource converter}}"
        Content="{Binding ElementName=parent,Path=LoadingContent}"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
    <ContentControl Visibility="{Binding ElementName=parent,Path=IsFailed,Converter={StaticResource converter}}"
                    Content="{Binding ElementName=parent,Path=FailedContent}"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

And here's missing event handler:

```
void OnImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.IsLoading = false;
    this.IsLoaded = true;
}
```

Comment: If your `Source` is `BitmapSource` you can try with [`BitmapSource.DownloadCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.downloadcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event

Answer (score 2):

Simle solution: Position the `Image` control on top of the control that displays the loading animation (e.g. by putting both inside the same `Grid`). As long as the image hasn't fully loaded it's transparent, letting the loading animation shine through, and after it has finished loading it automatically hides the animation.